# Можно ли в VisualStudio сразу компилировать 2 сборки X64 и X86?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

При компиляции на выбор всегда моно выбрать, что-то одно.

Можно ли сделать так, что бы сразу же компилировалось 2 сборки с разной разрядностью?

Есть AnyCpu, но в некоторых ситуациях он вызывает проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

Можно принудительно собирать обе конфигурации через AfterBuild:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <MSBuild Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x86' " Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Properties="Platform=x64;PlatFormTarget=x64" RunEachTargetSeparately="true" />
</Target>
```